# ffmpeg and windows command line

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, pascal, lazarus

I am trying to use ffmpeg for windows to convert thousands of images and sounds to a single video file.

```
ffmpeg -i apples.jpg -i oranges.jpg -i orangessound.wav -i bananas.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

My delphi program generates the command line as a string, and I use shellexecute to call it.

But is it true that a command line cannot be longer than 8191 characters? If so, can ffmpeg read the parameters from a file instead?

It is not possible in this case to rename the pictures with consecutive numbers

Comment: 32,768 characters, including the null terminator, as ShellExecute calls [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: why don't you call ffmpeg -i appels.jpg wait for it to finish then call ffmpeg -i oranges.jpg and so on..appending to the last outputed file?

Comment: Note path length might depend on Delphi/FPC versions (if -A and -W versions have different path length issues)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the open source [libavcodec library](http://ffmpeg.org/libavcodec.html) in your own code instead.  It is the same library that ffmpeg uses internally (there is a separate library called [libav](http://www.libav.org), which is an off-shoot of the original ffmpeg libavcodec library).  Then you can do whatever you want with the files.  You can look at the ffmpeg source code to see how it interprets the parameters you want to use, then adapt that logic to your own code.

Comment: You linked to a fork of FFmpeg. This does not include the `ffmpeg` source code.

Comment: Last time I downloaded libav/libavcodec, the ffmpeg source code was included as a demo project.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg does not support taking the entire command from file. you need to modify the code for your custom use.

it can take encoding parameter using "-fpre" option.